# Nextjs Candymachine Error

Tags: candy-machine-v2

I have tried to call getCandymachineState, but I received the error.

`Cannot read properties of null (reading 'state')`

Here is the code of the getCandymahchineState API

```
export default async function handler(
    req: NextApiRequest,
    res: NextApiResponse
  ) {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {

        // console.log(req.body);

        const {wallet,candyMachineId,rpcHost } : 
                {wallet: anchor.Wallet,
                candyMachineId: string,
                rpcHost: string} = req.body

      try {
                  
          const commitment: Commitment = 'confirmed';
          const connection = new anchor.web3.Connection(rpcHost, commitment);
          // console.log(connection);

          const candyMachine = new anchor.web3.PublicKey(candyMachineId!);
          console.log(candyMachine);

          // console.log(wallet);



          const provider = new anchor.Provider(connection, wallet, {
            preflightCommitment: 'processed',
          });
          // console.log(provider);
          // console.log(candyMachine);
        
          const idl = await anchor.Program.fetchIdl(candyMachine, provider);
          // console.log(idl);
        
          const program = new anchor.Program(idl!, candyMachine, provider);

        
          const state: any = await program.account.candyMachine.fetch(candyMachineId);
          console.log(state);
          const itemsAvailable = state.data.itemsAvailable.toNumber();
          const itemsRedeemed = state.itemsRedeemed.toNumber();
          const itemsRemaining = itemsAvailable - itemsRedeemed;

          
  
        res.status(200).json({
            id: candyMachineId,
            program,
            state: {
              authority: state.authority,
              itemsAvailable,
              itemsRedeemed,
              itemsRemaining,
              isSoldOut: itemsRemaining === 0,
              isActive: false,
              isPresale: false,
              isWhitelistOnly: false,
              goLiveDate: state.data.goLiveDate,
              treasury: state.wallet,
              tokenMint: state.tokenMint,
              gatekeeper: state.data.gatekeeper,
              endSettings: state.data.endSettings,
              whitelistMintSettings: state.data.whitelistMintSettings,
              hiddenSettings: state.data.hiddenSettings,
              price: state.data.price,
              retainAuthority: state.data.retainAuthority,
            },
          });
      } catch (err: any) {
        res.status(500).json({ statusCode: 500, message: err.message });
      }
    } else {
      res.setHeader('Allow', 'POST');
      res.status(405).end('Method Not Allowed');
    }
  }
```

Comment: You're going to need to ensure that the candy machine actually exists first. As of now you're accessing state when it may not exist. When you log the state does it return null?

Comment: The candy mahcine exists. when i use the example from candymachineui, the candy machine is working.

After I migrate the API to my own website, the candymachine doesn't work.

Comment: are you getting the IDL object

Comment: Yes, im trying to get the idl object, and the idl object returned null

Comment: Found the way. I forgot to input the cnadymachine program id.

Answer (score 1):

@AaronPang found the solution to this in his last comment: "Found the way. I forgot to input the cnadymachine program id."